# Possible to create a git repo that will comprised of files residing in NFS and files in a system directory?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to create a git repo that will include scripts in `/nfsdrive/sbin/` and the services that activate these scripts—which reside in `/etc/init.d/`.

I've searched the documentation and the relevant discussions, but could not find if the above is at all possible, much less how to accomplish it.

Is it possible to create a git repo that will comprised of files residing in NFS and files in a system directory?

Comment: Questions about how to use a tool should be asked on StackOverflow. This community is for conceptual questions about software engineering. You appear to have a concrete question about a tool, which makes this off-topic for this community. Consider rephrasing your question to make it on-topic (see [help/on-topic]) or post this on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, @greg.
I created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73085839/possible-to-create-a-git-repo-that-will-be-comprise-of-files-residing-in-nfs-and.
Should I delete the current question at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/439976?

Comment: Only delete this question if it is a duplicate of what you posted on StackOverflow.

Comment: Perhaps you could simply set up 2 separate git repos, one in each of those folders.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: this doesn't seem to be a question about *programming*, so I don't see how StackOverflow would be better. Perhaps you meant https://superuser.com/ ?

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a question about how to use a tool, but I will attempt a conceptual answer anyhow.

---

Instead of creating your git repository using the same file structure as a real server, consider storing the files all in one folder, but arranged into sub folders to represent where they should go. You could include a shell script that acts as an installer.

Basically, Git is good at storing files and version control, but not good at **deployment**. This is why version control and the logic for deploying code and configuration are their own specialized tools.

An idea for the structure of the repository could be:

```
./nfsdrive/sbin/
./etc/init.d/
./install.sh
```

If in your home directory, a `git clone <your repo>` would result in this file structure:

```
/users/boardrider/<your repo>/nfsdrive/sbin/
/users/boardrider/<your repo>/etc/init.d/
/users/boardrider/<your repo>/install.sh
```

Then you can execute `install.sh` with root permissions. This shell script could simply copy the files in `<your repo>` to their respective locations on the real machine.

It is a good idea to separate the storage of code from the logic that deploys it. This allows you to use specialized tools that are good at their respective jobs.